# FatalThrowableError Class 'App\Models\Patient' not found in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a model by using the command `php artisan make:model Patient`. The command creates a model named `Patient` in the app folder.

In Model Patient:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Patient extends Model
{
    //
    public function getPurchaseOrder(){
        return "Hello World";        
    }
}
```

In Controller PatientController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class PatientController extends Controller
{
  protected $patientModel;

public function __construct(Request $request, PatientInterface $patient)
    {
        parent::__construct($request);        
        $this->patientModel = new \App\Patient();
    }

   public function test(){
     echo $this->patientModel->getPurchaseOrder();
  }

}
```

It's working fine. The problem is when I create a folder named `Models` inside the app folder and move Patient model then call the model function it gives an error:

```
FatalThrowableError Class 'App\Models\Patient' not found
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @GhostCat, okay thanks, next time I will keep it in mind before voting up.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move a class to a different directory, for it to be loaded by composer with the [PSR-4 standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), you must also update the class' namespace to match.

```
namespace App\Models;
```

In addition, when you run the make command, you can include a namespace in that to automatically put it in the directory with the correct namespace:

```
php artisan make:model Models\\Patient
```